# How can I type a \ in the sqlcmd editor?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server

According to this [kb article on what to do if your user database is gone](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307864), it recommends the following three actions

```
sqlcmd –E -S InstanceName –d master
1> ALTER LOGIN SQLLogin WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = AvailDBName
2> GO
```

The problem here is the SQLLogin in this case is DOMAIN\user, but when I type that sqlcmd says
Incorrect syntax near '\'

I've tried DOMAIN\\user and 'DOMAIN\user' but neither work.

Comment: I typed that in the SF editor, but it collapsed it and I didn't notice, so yes, I tried that as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL is the command interpreter here, not the shell, so escaping with another \ will not work.  You have to surround the login with brackets.

```
ALTER LOGIN [DOMAIN\Username] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = AvailDBName
```

Answer (score 1):

you tried escaping it with another \ ? would be

```
 DOMAIN\\user
```

Comment: I typed that in the SF editor, but it collapsed it and I didn't notice (fixed now), so yes, I tried that as well.

Comment: No.  SQL is interpreting the command, not the shell.

Comment: Sorry, should have tested it first.